# Ruby on Rails Insert Raw Text between Loops

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I insert a raw text between every 2 loops from the index page

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
Content here ...
<% end %>
```

To show this results:

Post 1

post 2

RAW TEXT HERE

Post 3

Post 4

RAW TEXT HERE

Post 5

Post 6

RAW TEXT HERE

Post 7

Post 8

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that very easily like below code

```
<% @posts.each_with_index do |post, index| %>
    <%= post.title %>
    <% if index % 2 == 1 %>
        RAW TEXT HERE
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array#in_groups_of`](https://apidock.com/rails/Array/in_groups_of) to accomplish this:

```
<% @posts.in_groups_of(2, false) do |group| %>
  <% group.each do |post| %>
    <%= post.title %>
  <% end %>
  <%= raw_text %>
<% end %>
```

Replace `title` and `raw_text` with actual method names.

Comment: Adds an extra "raw_text" at the end, vs what the question requested.